# c# Convert variable value to object

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, unity-container

I need a way to convert the value of a variable into an object.

Lets assume a variable

```
string viewName = "taDataView";
```

I need a way to convert the value of variable into something like this:

```
taDataView viewModel = Container.Resolve<taDataView>();
```

Something like eval() in php...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You seems to be working with an IOC/DI framework. Can you mention which one ?

Comment: Using this on Silverlight with PRISM and Unity. This Container belongs to Unity.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Unity's Named Registrations (see Resolving an Object by Type and Registration Name in the Unity 2.0 help file). You would still need to know the base type (generally an interface).

```
// Create container and register types
var myContainer = new UnityContainer();
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyService, DataService>("Data");
myContainer.RegisterType<IMyService, LoggingService>("Logging");

// Retrieve an instance of each type
var myDataService = myContainer.Resolve<IMyService>("Data");
var myLoggingService = myContainer.Resolve<IMyService>("Logging");
```

Alternatively, see [Create an object knowing only the class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296251/create-an-object-knowing-only-the-class-name) (especially [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296251/create-an-object-knowing-only-the-class-name/296260#296260)).

**EDIT:** Revised the example to use generics.

Comment: Just corroborating your answer, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664762(v=pandp.50).aspx.