# How to initiate class with interface if you only know the class name in string

Tags: c#, class, interface

I have a interface named `IClass` declaring the method `Calculate` as below:

```
public interface IClass
{
   public int Calculate(int x);
}
```

Also I have 2 different classes implementing the above mentioned interface, `Class1` and `Class2`:

```
public class Class1: IClass
{
   public int Calculate(int x)
   {
      // do some calc with method 1 here
   }
}

public class Class2: IClass
{
   public int Calculate(int x)
   {
      // do some calc with method 2 here
   }
}
```

And then I want to call it from main class, however there is restriction where I don't know the class type, I only know the class string name (because it's a class library - other people may make the  code for it).

The question is: **how can I instantiate the particular class (and invoke the method `Calculate`) by knowing only its name ?**

```
public class MainForm()
{
    public int CalcUsing(string classname, int x)
    {
       IClass myclass = new Type(typeof(classname))()   // doesn't work here
       int result = myclass.Calculate(x);
       return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing the point of inheritance here. You are creating a contract with the IClass interface. Therefore, your method in MainForm CalcUsing should probably take a parameter of type IClass since you (as you have said) won't know the name of the class being passed in.  This gives someone the ability to declare a class implementing your interface and pass an instance of it to your form.

```
public int CalcUsing(IClass myClass, int x)
{
     int result = myclass.Calculate(x);
     return result;
}

class SomeClass : IClass
{
     //Implement the Calculate(int) method here
}

//Then the user of your class can do this with an instance of your form due to 
//SomeClass inheriting the IClass type
MainForm.CalcUsing(new SomeClass(), x);
```

Comment: Hi Shawn. That's a better approach. Thanks for the idea

Comment: Hi Denny,  mind crediting me with the answer?  I am new to SO and could use the rep points.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in using **[`Activator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.activator.aspx)** class:

```
try 
{
    // Get type
    Type t = Type.GetType(fullyQualifiedNameOfYourImplementingClass);

    // Instantiate
    IClass calculator = (IClass)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

    // Invoke
    calculator.Calculate(x);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // log exception and throw...
    throw ex;
}
```

There are a lot of resources for dynamic type instantiation, one can be found at [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296251/create-an-object-knowing-only-the-class-name).

**WARN:** in case that your implementing classes are located in a different assembly (as I guess is your case, please confirm), you need to get the `Type` from the `Assembly` the types are declared in, otherwise you will get a null value in this line: `Type t = Type.GetType(className);`.
In this direction we could rewrite the solution above like this:

```
// Get the assembly containing the implementations. I'm assuming both interface and implementation are in the same assembly
Assembly assembly = typeof(IClass).Assembly;

// Get type. note that know we made use of the aseembly to locate the Type.
Type t = assembly.GetType(className);
    IClass calculator = (IClass)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Be sure **`className` is a qualified name**.

Comment: The problem is Type t = Type.GetType(className) returns null.

Comment: Three questions: Are the classes (implementing the interface) in a different assembly (dll)? Have you added a reference in your project to that assembly? className, is that containing a qualified name (including namespace) or just the class name?

Comment: Hi Luis I think I got the answer. Since the IClass (interface assembly) is on separate assembly from Class1 and Class2 (plugin assembly). So I need to load the plugin assembly instead of the interface assembly: Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(pluginFile); this solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Remember next time to provide as much as possible useful information about your problem so that we don't need to guess or assume that might not apply for your circumstance. Anyway, good that you got your problem solved!