# How do I declare and invoke a C# object when given the object name as a string?

Tags: c#, string, class, object, reflection

Because I haven't entered the namespace + the name of the class (I only entered the class name) i received an Exception error.

I have a lot of classes written and I receive a String. I want directly to declare and initiate the class that the value of the String is. I don't want to browse every single class written to see which is. Here is an example:

```
class Car
{
      public void startCar()
      {
            Console.WriteLine("Car started");
      }
}

class Main
{
      private void treeView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         String s="Car"
        // I said Car obj because that's the value of the string
         Car obj = new Car();

         // or like this
         value.string obj = new value.string();
         obj.startCar();


      }



}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296251/create-an-object-knowing-only-the-class-name

Comment: What error /problem do you get?

Comment: Simplest way is `Console.WriteLine(GetType().Name));`.

Comment: I know for sure that it's only on class with that exact name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an instance of a class from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223952/create-an-instance-of-a-class-from-a-string)

Comment: The above duplicate is the first google result for "create class from string c#"...

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Single(_ => _.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == name) != null).GetType(name).GetMethod("SomeMethodToInvoke").Invoke(null, null);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use reflection, but you need a fully qualified class name, so if you have only the class name, you have to decide a default namespace:

```
Type objType = Type.GetType("TheNamespace." + className); 
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
MethodInfo myMethod = objType.GetMethod(methodName);
myMethod.Invoke(obj,   // The object on which to invoke the method
                null); // Argument list for the invoked method
```

If all the classes you have to instantiate expose the same method that then you have to call, you can define a common `Interface` for all those classes:

```
interface MyInterface
{
    void showData();
}

class MyClass : MyInterface
{

    public void showData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass");
    }
}

class MyClass2 : MyInterface
{
    public void showData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass2");
    }
}
```

Then cast the instance of the object to MyInterface and invoke the method:

```
// Using MyClass
Type objType = Type.GetType("VsLogAnalyzer." + "MyClass");
MyInterface myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(objType) as MyInterface;
myObj.showData();
// Using MyClass2
objType = Type.GetType("VsLogAnalyzer." + "MyClass2");
myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(objType) as MyInterface;
myObj.showData();
```

Comment: @ClaudiuLazăr do all types that you have to instantiate expose `startCar()` method? Or do you have also to call it from a string?

Comment: i have only one method in every single class and it's named showData() with no parameters. 
I keep getting null pointer exception when i try to invoke the function

Comment: @ClaudiuLazăr How do you invoke it? What does the exception's stack trace says?

Answer (score 0):

```
  // I had the problem that the program didn't find the specific class
  // This is the code that I used and it helped me resolve the exception by entering the namespace also




     // the s is the string

       Type objType = Type.GetType("Namespace." + s);
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);


        MethodInfo Method = objType.GetMethod("showData");
        object Value = Method.Invoke(obj,null);
        richTextBox1.Text = Value.ToString();
```

THX a lot @codroipo